# php - laravel lost login session when another project on the same server running huge db job

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

There is a situation that laravel lost login session when another project on the same server running huge db job.

Two project are hosted in the same apache/nginx and using laravel 5.4. But they have different session cookie name.

What another project is doing is just get data from db, change a value and update it.

Here is what i get when dumping the session(bying session()->all()).

*before another project run the job*

`"_token" => "1RHWi0cOzmTKtNvQRfpSiuKY8XrMTPyaRVmOrjZ1"
"login_admin_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 10`

*when another project runing huge db job*

`"_token" => "a48IdcffgDsqqPM0Z3c3w8HlQcBSEpniMVJb25g5"`

*after cancel (in broswer) the running the job of another project*

`"_token" => "1RHWi0cOzmTKtNvQRfpSiuKY8XrMTPyaRVmOrjZ1"
"login_admin_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 10`

The session drive is file. I've tried to change session drive to cookie and database but none of them work.

Anyone has ideas about how to fix it? thank a lot!!!

Comment: Do you have the different2 key for both projects?
I hope you have not copied the folder with basic structure?

Comment: @DsRaj  do you mean the APP_KEY in dotenv file ? They are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by a thread safety issue using `getenv()`. When one laravel project is runing and its `.env` is loaded. While anthor project runs at the same time and it find the env is already set and just use it.

To fix it:

1. Using different env variable name. e.g. In project A, APP_URL_A = ***,  for B, using APP_URL_B
2. Writing env in vhost configuration
3. If using laravel, cache the config (by running `php artisan config:cache`)

helpful links:
https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/219

Comment: 1st and 2nd method not tried, but 3rd method worked and no need for restart server!